# nginx root inside home directory - forbidden 403

Tags: linux, nginx

I want my nginx to server files from my user home directory, but I keep getting error 403 forbidden.

nginx.conf

```
user http;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    #server_name_in_redirect off;

    root   /home/txx/http/www;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php56-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

I have directory /home/user/http/www and all subfolders set to 775 with, and all belongs to http group.

> drwxrwxr-x 10 txx http   4096 20.04.2017 19:28 www/

I've run 'chmod 755 -R www/*' 'chmod 775 -R www'

What could be this about?

Comment: You're using php-fpm, is that user also able to access the directory?

Comment: If you're running a system that's using SELinux make sure it's either disabled using `setenforce 0` or make sure that the proper context is set on the directory and the correct selinux boolean `httpd_read_user_content_t` and `httpd_enable_homedirs`

Also see [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/686732/nginx-refuses-to-read-new-directory-in-home)

Comment: @Seth I do not see user named 'php-fpm' in my system, neither a group called like this. Do you have another thought about this issue?  What is curious about this 'forbidden' situation, is that it still happens even when all my directory tree is set to 777.

Comment: @Patrick I do not use SELinux, I am running Chakra which is based on Arch Linux.

Comment: The name of the user would depend on your PHP configuration. You're using a socket to interact with another daemon that is probably running using a different user and that user might be lacking permission to do stuff.

Comment: In php-fpm.conf the user and group are both set to 'http', this is the same user that nginx daemon is set to. Either way, should't the nginx display static html without concern?